# Can I make any tests statistically significant?

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample-size, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am using a simple $\chi^2$ test to see if there is any impact of an independent variable (two charts) on the resulting choices (two choices). I found that as the number of sample increase, the $p$-value is decreasing (type I error is decreasing). What about type II error? Is this decreasing as well because we collect more samples?

If this is true, does this mean that if I can collect more and more data, can I make any $\chi^2$ test statistically significant? If this is true, I feel like that I am cheating.

(Actually, we collect data through Amazon Mechanical Turk, so collecting more data is not that difficult).

Comment: please present your charts. The increase in sample-size does reduce the scope for Type I error.

Comment: Actually sequential testing without correction *is* cheating. You need to apply any method to correct for multiple testing in order to keep overall type 1 error low. In oncology, such  designs are quite common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you collect more data, eventually any effect size will become significant.

This isn't cheating, this is part of the problem of using p-values instead of focusing on effect sizes.

Also, with chisquare, there really is no dependent and independent variable - you may want to consider a logistic regression.

Comment: Any non-zero effect size - & what effect sizes in the world are really, exactly, zero?

Comment: Yes. I suppose, in a chi square, it is possible to find an exact 0 effect size.

Comment: @PeterFlom I don't see how the effect size would remain zero, at least not as the sample size is changing.

Comment: @Glen_b if the table were 2x2, then as long as n is divisible by 4, you *could* have an exactly 0 effect size.

Comment: @PeterFlom Perhaps we're talking at cross purposes. Are you taking the population size to be the grand total in the 2x2 table?

Comment: No, the sample size. e.g. a sample of 100,000 divided into (25,000, 25,000, 25,000, 25,000) has exact 0 effect. Astronomically unlikely, but theoretically possible.